# Will a longer (more specific) child selector be faster than a shorter (less specific) descendant selector?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am fixing my old css file, and wanted to do some minor improvements in it. I am confused which would be faster/more efficient in the following rules:

```
.box>tr>td[colspan]>a>img
```

or

```
.box td[colspan] img
```

I have read that CSS selectors are evaluated from right to left, but since children selectors are more efficient/faster than descendant selectors, I am thinking that the first rule is better. But since `a` and `tr` will also be evaluated in the first rule, then does that mean skipping them by using the second rule would be more efficient/faster?

P.S. I cannot add class selectors at the moment since the site is static and would be tedious to restructure.

Comment: Personally, I won't worry much about CSS selector performance, and I usually tend to use selectors that are simpler, less specific and so it's easier to override later if I need to override in another selector

Comment: In my experience, the shorter the selector (without make thing overlap the wrong way) the better. Because it make override the rules simpler when/if the need arise without the need for `!important`, or if you change layout/class/tag you won't have to rewrite much, and it easier to read too. (And it can even help performance)